# Pass username and password in URL for authentication

Tags: iphone, ios, url, nsurl

I want ot pass username and password in URL(web service) for user authentication which will return true and false.I'm doing this as following:

```
NSString *userName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"parameterUser=%@",txtUserName];
NSString *passWord = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"parameterPass=%@",txtPassword];
NSData *getUserData = [userName dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *getUserLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[getUserData length]];
NSData *getPassData = [passWord dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *getPassLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[getPassData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://URL/service1.asmx"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
```

Now, I wanted to know How can I pass my username and password in this URL to make request.
Could any one please suggest or give some sample code?
Thanks.

Comment: I guess this is for exercising, because that's highly insecure.

Comment: You should really not put the username or password in the URL. Instead it should be in the headers, or body, preferably encoded/encrypted, sent over https (secure http).

Comment: @Paaske Thanks for this suggestion. Actually I want to make it secure.How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
NSString *userName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"parameterUser=%@",txtUserName.text];
    NSString *passWord = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"parameterPass=%@",txtPassword.text];
    NSData *getUserData = [userName dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *getUserLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[getUserData length]];
    NSData *getPassData = [passWord dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *getPassLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[getPassData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://URL/service1.asmx?%@&%@",userName,passWord]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
```

Hope it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://URL/service1.asmx?%@&%@",userName,passWord];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
```

Comment: Thanks for this code.But will it be secure?If not, How can I make a secure connection?

Comment: It depends whether you server is expecting usrName/pswd in post data or not. Usually credentials are set in post data. I don't know what your server is expecting

Comment: My DB is expecting string.Do you mean, it should be like this to make secure?[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://URL/service1.asmx?%@&%@",userName,passWord]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; or anything need to be added?

Answer (score 0):

First off I would not pass a username and password across in a url. You should do this using post.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://URL/service1.asmx?"]];

NSString *userName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"parameterUser=%@",txtUserName];
NSString *passWord = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"parameterPass=%@",txtPassword];
NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",userName, passWord];
NSData *postData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [postString UTF8String] length: [postString length]];

//URL Requst Object
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:TIMEOUT];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody: postData];
```

This is more secure then passing sensitive data across in a url.

**Edit**

To get the response you can check this out. [NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270447/how-to-use-sendasynchronousrequestqueuecompletionhandler) and [AppleDoc NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

You can use a few different methods to handle the response from the server.
You can use [`NSURLConnectionDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate)

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[self.connection start];
```

along with the delegate call backs:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    NSLog(@"didReceiveData");
    if (!self.receivedData){
        self.receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
    }
    [self.receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
    NSString *receivedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"receivedString:%@",receivedString);

}
```

Or you can also use [`NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9270711/1144161) block

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
    NSString *receivedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"receivedString:%@",receivedString);

}];
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion; How do I check, success or fail(i.e. true or false),Because my web service returns "true" or "false" depending on success or fails.Also, what is the value of this "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and "Content-Type", could i keep it as it is? I'm new to this,please suggest.

Comment: Looks your suggestion is more appropriate, could you please give more idea or response to my comment?Thanks.

Comment: I added an edit to my post that has links to how to get the returned response from the server. I will add another edit with some example code.

Answer (score 0):

To improve the secure , you may use the Http [Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). 
There are answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14799788/2053030).

Comment: I do not want to use basic authentication, because my networks are not trusted.Thanks.