# error while making URL request iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, url

I asked a question and followed following way(suggested by Jaybit):
[Pass username and password in URL for authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812865/pass-username-and-password-in-url-for-authentication/14814152#14814152)

Now, I'm getting this error(stack track):

```
2013-02-12 11:56:11.734 Calendar[4074:c07] didReceiveData
2013-02-12 11:56:19.519 Calendar[4074:c07] receivedString:<?xml version="1.0"      encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><soap:Code><soap:Value>soap:Receiver</soap:Value></soap:Code><soap:Reason><soap:Text xml:lang="en">System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.SoapEnvelopeReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()
   at  System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.SoapEnvelopeReader.MoveToContent()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocolHelper.GetRequestElement()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap12ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext  context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean&amp; abortProcessing)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</soap:Text></soap:Reason><soap:Detail /> </soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
(lldb)
```

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)btnLoginClick:(id)sender
 {
//Call Calendar View
if(self.viewController == nil) {
    CalendarViewController *detailView = [[CalendarViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CalendarViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.viewController = detailView;

}
NSString *userName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"parameterUser=%@",txtUserName];
NSString *passWord = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"parameterPass=%@",txtPassword];


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://URL/service1.asmx?"]];

NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",userName, passWord];
NSLog(@"%@",userName);
NSLog(@"%@",passWord);

NSData *postData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [postString UTF8String] length: [postString length]];

//URL Requst Object
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:600];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody: postData];
appConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[self.appConnection start];
```

//tryed with Async...

```
   /* NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
    NSString *receivedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"receivedString:%@",receivedString);

}];*/

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.viewController animated:YES];
```

}

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
tempdata = data;
NSLog(@"didReceiveData");
if (!self.receivedData){
    self.receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
}
[self.receivedData appendData:data];
    }

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
 {

    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
NSString *receivedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:tempdata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"receivedString:%@",receivedString);
```

}

please help.thank.

Comment: have you check your URL in any whitespace..? then you put %20

Comment: Please post a complete question.  I have no idea what you want.

Comment: Hi Nitin,the URL working fine from Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked with requesting a soap URL before, the following code worked for me:

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                         "<YourServiceName xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                         "<username>%@</username>\n"
                         "<passowrd>%@</passowrd>\n"
                         "</YourServiceName>\n"
                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>\n", userName, passWord
                         ];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://URL/service1.asmx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];
[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://tempuri.org/%@",service] forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[theRequest setTimeoutInterval:10];
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if( theConnection )
{
    responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}
```

Comment: Thanks.What is "service" in your answer?

Comment: Could any one please tell me what "service" mean over here? [theRequest addValue: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://tempuri.org/%@",service] forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"]; Is this my web service name? if yes,what is the proper format??

Comment: Yes, it's your service name, it should be like YourServiceName.

Comment: Is it means I need to give complete URL? or part of it; like, "/URL/service1.asmx". Pl suggest?

Comment: Again, after giving full URL, its saying "failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode" and my "responseData" does not have any value.

Comment: Hardcoding username and password in SOAP,is working fine.But "NSString stringwithformat" is not working.Note:- I'm taking username and password from two UItextfield like this:-NSString *userName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"parameterUser=%@",txtUserName];
    NSString *passWord = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"parameterPass=%@",txtPassword]; .Please suggest?Thanks.

Comment: Now,its working fine.Thanks.Updated SOAP:-NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
    "<soap:Body>\n"
    "<MethodName xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
    "<Parameter1>%@</Parameter1>\n"
    "<Parameter2>%@</Parameter2>\n"
    "</MethodName>\n"
    "</soap:Body>\n"
    "</soap:Envelope>\n",Parameter1,Parameter2];